# Oracle Apex Dialog Page Loads Infinitely

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

In my Oracle Apex application, I have a page with a branch that is supposed to open a dialog page.  When the branch is triggered the dialog seems to load correctly but the loading symbol never goes away.  If I attempt to open a regular page in the branch it works fine and during my debugging process I tried multiple different dialog pages within the app that work fine when called from different pages, but when called from this one specific page it doesn't work.

If I look at the debug logs it seems that everything is executed properly and reaches their final commits.  Any help would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE: Recreating the page yielded the same results, but I did realize that the error only occurs if the dialog is called from a branch, adding a button that when clicked goes to the same dialog page works just fine.

Comment: First, **export** page (for backup purposes). Then try to create another page as a *copy* of this one (that caused problems) and use that "new" page for branch. If it doesn't help, try to create a brand new page.

Comment: I would also check the browser console for any JS errors. Maybe something broke, and the command to remove the spinner never executes.

Comment: Just did a test. Created a normal page with just a button that redirects to a modal window with a branch. The loading icon appears for a second and disappears. Can you create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com for us to have a look ?

Comment: The JS browser console had no errors but turning off the "Show processing" option in the DA settings that submits the page fixed the issue.  Will this solution have consequences that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
See [Oracle forum](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/branching-to-modal-9350)

Comment: I am using Oracle Version 20.2, this bug shouldn't apply to me